# Qt Creator not suggesting member methods of objects inside non-Qt containers

Tags: qt, qt-creator

In Qt Creator, if I have a `QList<SomeClass*>` called `someList`, and I type

```
someList[0].
```

it shows a list of all the members of SomeClass, and converts the "." into "->", which is great. However, if I do the same with an std::vector, I get no suggestions nor a conversion. I can still type out the code myself and it will work, though.

Is there any way I can make Qt Creator suggest the members of objects in non-Qt containers?

I'm using Qt Creator 2.4.1.

Comment: Hopefully someone can correct me if I'm wrong, but I always assumed Qt parses doxygen commenting when indexing 'included' files.  I haven't looked, but I imagine the standard library headers included in your OS don't use doxygen.

Comment: @cnmannett85 Interesting... do you know any doxygen comments that might be relevant?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, relevant to what?

Comment: @cnmannett85 I mean are special doxygen comments I can put into my header files that Qt Creator can parse so that it can "recognize" members of contained objects? That is, if I've understood your initial comment correctly. I should have clarified that this happens not only for std::vector but also in my own container classes, and that if adding doxygen comments is the only way to resolve the situation, I'd like to be able to do that at least in my own classes.

Comment: No, something else is wrong if it is not parsing files that are a part of your project.  Code completion works fine for me for un-doxygen-ed classes, as long as they are a part of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creator actually parses the C++ code and ignores comments, so doxygen will not help here;-)
It will parse all files in your project as well as everything those include, using the include paths to find those if necessary.

No, there is currently no way to make Creator do that. The codemodel Creator uses is a bit limited when it comes to templates, so those tend to have no completion. It tends to fail rather often with QLists, too.

There is work ongoing to get that fixed by using the clang code model which is way more exact than the one we currently use, but unfortunately that is also way slower (not surprising as Creators will just take shortcuts wherever something takes too much time:-). Currently that is just not usable, it takes way too long to get the initial parsing that is required for code completion and syntax highlighting to work. We are looking at how this can be improved by either improving clang for our usecase or caching information or something.

Maybe we will just end up fixing up our existing code model a bit in the end or use ours for fast initial parsing and only follow up with clang later to improve on the data we extracted before.